# How can I get from Sausalito to Muir Woods on Friday?

Tags: transportation, california, san-francisco, national-parks

I mean really, [it's only eight miles](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Sausalito,+CA/Muir+Woods+National+Monument,+1+Muir+Woods+Rd,+Mill+Valley,+CA+94941/@37.891335,-122.5628207,13z). Here's our plan:

1. Take a ferry from our hotel in SF to Sausalito on Friday, June 12. It can be any time on Friday, I don't really care.
2. Get from Sausalito to Muir Woods. This is the problem.
3. Go back.

Our problem is that [the shuttle (66F) that normally serves this](http://www.marintransit.org/routes/66.html) starts June 22. This will not work.

We could take normal public transportation, but Google says that's a 1 h 42 min bus ride, with a terrible looking route:

[image]

- We're both in good shape, and can walk several miles if need be.
- We're not dead set on going to the actual visitors' center - is there a closer spot that still has trees and paths and such?
- I really don't like walking in places of questionable safety. But I'll do it if I have to.

So how can I get from Sausalito to Muir Woods on Fri June 12?

Comment: Is renting a car an option?

Comment: Does it have to be Friday? The shuttle runs on weekends off-season.

Comment: You could take a taxi, Uber, Lyft, etc... Note that cell phone service is fairly poor around Muir Woods (depending on your carrier), so it might be best to arrange a preset time for the taxi driver to pick you back up.

Comment: At what time of day? The bus routes shown aren't really that far off from the driving route, and they do vary based on time of day.

Comment: Really any time on Friday (or Thursday, for that matter), @michaelhampton.

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2Rio suggests various options](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Sausalito/Muir-Woods-National-Monument) including public transport, taking a taxi, and driving. All in all the hassle-free option would be the taxi. Rome2Rio quotes approximately 30`USD` for the journey. It's a bit steep, but you're talking about ~13km. If not you can always rent a car and travel at your own schedule. I doubt that will be cheaper than 60`USD` though (2 times the cab fare for a return journey).